# Is $S^1 \times S^1$ really a torus?

Tags: calculus, integration, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Consider a function $f(x)$ that is $2\pi$ periodic. Consider another function $g(y)$ that is also $2\pi$ periodic. If I wanted to compute the integral of either of these functions I would do so according to:
$$ \int_{a}^{b} f(x)\text{d}x$$
or
$$ \int_{c}^{d} g(y)\text{d}y$$

Now, consider a function $h(x,y) = f(x)g(y)$. If I wanted to compute the integral of such a function I would intuitively use:
$$ \int_{a}^{b}\int_{c}^{d} f(x)g(y)\text{d}x\text{d}y$$

However, the domain of $h(x,y)$ is $S^1 \times S^1$, and so can be seen as a unit torus. The area element that I have used above is $\text{d}x\text{d}y$, but the area element of a unit torus is $(1+\cos(x))\text{d}x\text{d}y$. **What is the correct area element to use when integrating the function $h(x,y)$ above? Why?**

Comment: Where did you get $(1+\cos(x))\;dx\;dy$?  What is it *really* an area element for... since it it not the area element to use in your case.

Comment: The torus has many (Riemannian) metrics. One of them is even flat!

Comment: @GEdgar: There are many sources for this area element on a torus, one is given in Eq. 29 [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Torus.html), where the radii $a$ and $c$ I have set to unity to get $(1+\cos(x))\text{d}x\text{d}y$

Comment: @ZhenLin: Why are there different metrics for the torus? Which one applies in my case? Why would you use one over another?

Comment: There are uncountably many Riemannian metrics on *any* (positive-dimensional) manifold. If $g$ is a metric, $f^2 g$ is a metric for $f: M \to \Bbb R$ any smooth function. And even then, you can write down infinitely many metrics on the torus, none of which has $g' = f^2 g$ for some smooth $f$. (In other words, none of them are conformally equivalent.)

Comment: @MikeMiller: So how do I know which one to use for the specific problem given in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You started with an ordinary planar integral over a rectangle in the plane. Then you chose to view it as an integral over a torus. By interpreting the Euclidean integral
$$
\int_{a}^{b} \int_{c}^{d} f(x) g(y)\, dx\, dy
$$
as an integral over a torus, you implicitly *chose* the unique flat metric isometric to the rectangle $[a, b] \times [c, d]$ with boundary identifications.

The deeper message is that you can't invariantly integrate a continuous function over a smooth $n$-manifold; you need extra structure, such as a volume form (a continuous, non-vanishing $n$-form), a volume density (the absolute value of a volume form), or a Riemannian metric.